# Different $_SERVER output when running from command line or system()

Tags: php, command-line-interface

If have these very simple scripts:

***foo.php:***

```
<?php
system("php -c /etc/php7/cli/php.ini /some-path/exec.php");
?>
```

***exec.php:***

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

Running `exec.php` from command line I get the expected output for `$_SERVER`:

```
...
[LESSKEY] => /etc/lesskey.bin
[NNTPSERVER] => news
[MANPATH] => /usr/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man
[XDG_SESSION_ID] => 2
[HOSTNAME] => AAEB-DEV203LD
[XKEYSYMDB] => /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/XKeysymDB
[HOST] => AAEB-DEV203LD
[TERM] => linux
[SHELL] => /bin/bash
...
```

When `exec.php` is executed by the `system` function in the `foo.php` script called in a browser tab then the output for `$_SERVER` is totally different and it looks more or less exactly like the `Environment` section from `phpinfo()`:

```
...
    [APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES] => 
    [mpm_found] => true
    [APACHE_CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS] => 
    [SYSCONFIG_FILE] => /etc/sysconfig/apache2
    [APACHE_START_TIMEOUT] => 2
    [HTTPD_MODULE_IDS] =>  actions_module alias_module ...
    [APACHE_SERVERNAME] => 
...
```

***What is the problem:***

In the `$_SERVER` output - running via `system()` function - there is missing lot of information which we need.

I didn't find anything in the Internet which can give me a hint why the output differs so much.

OS: SLES 12.3
PHP: 7.2.10
Apache: 2.4 MPM

**My question:**

Why does the output differ so much when running under command line and `system()` within the Apache session and can I get the same output for the `system()` function when calling `exec.php` from the command line with `php -c /etc/php7/cli/php.ini /some-path/exec.php`?

Comment: Most of that stuff (LESSKEY, XKEYSYMDB, ...) is not what you normally find in $_SERVER, so your system must explicitly add those values somewhere. First guess would be ENV variables set by your web server, those would naturally not exist when you execute PHP via CLI …

Comment: Yes, it is from the environment. You could confirm this by running `printenv` in your PHP script. Most of these variables are configured from shell scripts invoked via /etc/bash_rc, /etc/bash_profile and/or /etc/profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good. I could sort it out how it works, it wasn't clear to me.

Running `php` from command line PHP sets into `$_SERVER` all exported environment variables. Therefore `$_SERVER` has the entry `HOSTNAME`.

Running `exec()` from a script which is executed in a browser tab PHP sets `$_SERVER` with the content of `Environment` section as displayed by `phpinfo()`.

When I want to have set the entry `HOSTNAME` in `$_SERVER` I have to call `putenv("HOSTNAME=value");` before `exec()`.